# Not able to locate elements which gets generate dynamically in Appium android

Tags: android, appium

I am trying to automate a native android app with appium + java client.
I am using uiautomatorviewer to locate elements.

In the app there is one page for commenting.
So comments will be generated dynamically.

UIAutomatorview can locate these dynamically generate elements.
But through appium I get `NoSuchElementException`.

I am using appium 1.3.6

My code to get the WebElement:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id(<tagName>:id/scrolling_list_item));
```

But appium is not able to identify element.

I got this ID from uiautomatorviewer.

Comment: It would be great of see the code you are using and the snapshot of the UIAutomator. then only anyone can say anything!!

Comment: I added my code. Can you please check once. Any help will be greatly appreciated.!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Try to change the configuration of automation name to appium, do not use seledroid]
Try to change the configuration of automation name to appium, do not use seledroid

Answer (score 0):

You have written the code like this.

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id(:id/scrolling_list_item));
```

Modify this as below:

```
WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.id("scrolling_list_item"));
```